# How do I make my fonts render smoother?

Tags: html, css

The fonts are being rendered crisply to a fault, such that the edges are all jagged. Being a minimalist site, I'm trying to get everything perfect.

How do I fix this? http://individual.utoronto.ca/andrewlouis

Comment: Looks fine for me (Chrome 19.0). What browser are you using?

Comment: You can't. Fonts only render in one way in a web browser, and that's how the browser decides to render them on the screen. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx _(Why fonts look much better in IE9, especially Wikipedia and Facebook. Only IE9 has ClearType, the rest have OpenType.)_

Comment: Chrome as well, an older one though, I'll download the new one and check it out William. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font rendering is browser-specific and operating-specific.

There's very little you can do to control how the fonts are rendered, and what you see in your browser is not how other users will see it in theirs.

[This article](http://blog.typekit.com/2010/10/21/type-rendering-web-browsers/) is a bit old now, but it does explain the differences very well between the various browsers and how they render text.

And here's a question over on Webdesign.stackoverflow that asks how to make fonts render the same across all browsers: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9972/how-can-i-make-fonts-render-the-same-way-across-different-web-browsers

The answers given there might help you, but the basic answer is that there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: More recent article : http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/24/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/

Comment: @benoît - thank you. I had the other article in my bookmarks. It is still relevant but clearly out-dated, so a newer article link is a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

For much better / smoother text in Chrome and Safari, try the CSS:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

It appears however that `-moz-font-smoothing` was once available to use, but is no longer available. Fonts do tend to be smoother in Firefox anyways it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`font-smooth` css property. See docs: http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspfontsmooth.htm
Also here: http://www.cssportal.com/css-properties/font-smooth.htm

See Font Rendering Differences: Firefox vs. IE vs. Safari
http://css-tricks.com/font-rendering-differences-firefox-vs-ie-vs-safari/

Comment: This property doesn't seem to work? Notepad++ doesn't syntax highlight it and I see no noticeable difference after changing that attribute.